# Measure elapsed time between some code segments in Android

Tags: android

everyone. I'm a newbie to android, so please forgive me for asking questions that may be a bit elementary.
I need to calculate the running time (in nanoseconds) of a code segment, and I just started using System.nanoTime(), something like this:

```java
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
// some code seqment
long endTime = System.nanoTime();

long elapsedTime = startTime - endTime;
```

But I've observed online that sometimes `elapsedTime` is a negative number! After checking, it seems that the problem is due to the size of the cores in android, the frequency of the two cores is different and if my `starttime` and `endTime` run on different cores, the calculation is not credible.

I found [elapsedRealTime,elpseRealTimeNanos](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html), in the android documentation and they seem to meet my needs, but I don't know if they have the same problem as `System.nanoTime`, and I didn't find them on google, so I would like to ask if these two functions can meet my needs

Answer (score 0):

It must be `endTime - startTime` to get positive number.

`long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;`

OR you can try to use `elapsedRealtime`. (Not that it changed if device is reboot).

```
val startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
// your code segment
val elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime
```